# Imperial palace wall names

Tags: warhammer-40k

From a book called I am Slaughter we get to know that there are 50 walls/gates on the Imperial Palace on Earth

Some of them:

- Daylight
- Tranquility
- Zarathrusa
- Bastion Gate

I was wondering if there is a comprehensive list naming all 50 somwhere in the GW lore?

Comment: I think GW usually tries to avoid comprehensively listing anything, so there is always room for fans to name them for themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Brian said, there is probably no comprehensive list of walls and gates. There are some maps out there, e.g this map from [The Lost and Damned](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/The_Lost_and_the_Damned_(Novel)):

[image: Map of the Imperial Palace]

Looking at the map for the Lion's Gate Defence, we see a further gate behind the Lion's Gate, the Ultimate Gate. Also, wall sections have their own names:

[image: Map for the defence of the Lion's Gate]

At the same time, we see that the between the towers are not named on the Lion's Gate map. I think it very probable for the Custodes to name these walls also just to be half a second faster in communicating (instead of having to say "between A and B" being able to say "Wall Q"). So, getting a comprehensive list of all the walls and gates is very improbable as not only the walls have names but each wall consists of sections with an own name, each section has subsections etc.

For humans, such a system would be absolutely overkill and couldn't be handled. For Custodes, knowing the name and exact location (and very probable the available defence, strength of the wall section etc.) is childs play.